# Is there a way to get ipaddresses of all the websites in the world to a txt file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, web, ip-address

I have written a python program to ping a website using its ipaddress to check whether it is alive or not. The program works great when online by getting the ipaddress of the website and process it for further analysis.

Here's the sample Code:

```
def ip_address_web(hosts,port):
        alladdr = list(set(map(lambda x: x[4],socket.getaddrinfo(hosts,port))))
        global IPV4A, IPV6A, ip6array
        ip4array = []
        ip4 = filter(lambda x: '.' in x[0],alladdr)
        for addr4 in ip4:
            ip4 = addr4
            ipv4a = addr4[0]
            ip4 = ipaddress.ip_address(ipv4a)
            print(ip4.version)
            ip4array.append(ipv4a)
        print(ip4array)
        IPV4A = ip4array[0]
        try:
            print("ip6 check")
            ip6 = filter(lambda x: ':' in x[0],alladdr)
            ip6array = []
            for addr6 in ip6:
                ip6 = addr6
                ipv6a = addr6[0]
                ip6 = ipaddress.ip_address(ipv6a)
                ip6array.append(ipv6a)
            print(ip6array)
            IPV6A = ip6array[0]
        except:
            IPV6A = []
            print("ipv6a:",IPV6A)
            print("No IPv6 address")
hosts = "www.google.com"
port = 80
ip_address_web(hosts,port)
```

But in offline, the code fails to get ipaddress for further processing. So instead of getting ipaddress  from online, I want to make it available offline. So i need to know that is there a way to get the ipaddresses of all the websites in a txt file.

When i connected to online, I can get the ipaddress of any website by using my python program or searching it on Google. But in offline, it is not possible. So I am making another python program to get the ipaddresses of all the websites and store it in a txt file to make it available for offline. Is that possible?? Are there any library in python consists of all ipaddresses of websites. I searched in Google but can't find one. Any solutions please...

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think there is a library in python that contains IPs of all the websites on the internet. You will have to manually built the list of websites you want to test.

```
websites = ["www.yahoo.com", "www.google.com"]
with open("ips.txt", "w+") as fh:
    for i in websites:
        fh.write(gethostbyname(i)+"\n")
```

Later you can read the IPs from this file and test your connectivity.

Further a simple search reveals that  there are almost 200 million live websites, let alone total number of websites which is more than 1 billion. So even you have a file containing IPs of lets say 100 million web sites, imagine how much time it would take to iterate or lookup such a big file !!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if the user queried any other website apart from text file, it is difficult to process for me. So for that reason, i need IPs of all the websites to be hold in the txt file. How did the various ipchecker websites holds ipaddresses of all websites

Comment: As per my knowledge there isn't and there are almost 200 million live websites. let alone total number of websites, so even you have a file containing IPs of lets say 100 million web sites, it would take a long time to even iterate through the file !!

Comment: Change your approach. No such list can be be constructed because the internet is decentralized. Any IP address can host a website. Anyone can setup a web server on an IP they control (or take it down) without notifying you (or anyone) to update your list.

Comment: @ewindes i assume your comment was not me !!